# How can I increase my carrying bag/capacity size in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a way to increase the amount of items that I can carry with me in Diablo 3, much like you could purchase more/bigger bags in WoW?

Comment: Don't pickup white/gray items.  They aren't worth the time it takes to manage them.

Comment: You wouldn't suggest picking them up and filling my bags with them until my bags are 75% full, leaving the rest of the space for the rarer items, and then selling it all once I get back to town?

Comment: They really sell for like 5 gold each.  If you put the time spent picking them up and going back to town to sell them into killing things, you'd probably end up with more gold.

Comment: @bwarner True. However, when clicking for the gold, I always end up accidentally picking up the items even though I don't really click on them; is there a trick to it?

Comment: @John Well, there's nothing stopping you from just letting it stay in your inventory until you need the space. Then purge white/grey items and continue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, like its predecessors you can not increase your carrying capacity. However items take significantly less space in Diablo 3 over Diablo 2 (however more space than WoW), allowing you to carry a surprisingly large amount of items.

You can store items in your Stash however, which can be upgraded in size.

Answer (score 6):

You can teleport back to town at almost any time you want, and unlimited times.  So if your bags ever fill up just go back to town, empty them, and then jump back in right where you left off.  Full bags should never be a problem.

Comment: When I first posted this, I didn't know the Town Portal button existed!

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to increase your pack size, all items take up space. Even those in their dedicated storage containers. I.e - Blacksmithing materials. Try storing this stuff in your stash until you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**No you can't**

There is no way you can increase your inventory size in Diablo 3 (But you can buy extra space for your stash). [In Diablo 2 you could use some tricks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64969/is-there-a-way-to-increase-inventory-size-in-diablo-ii) and Wow you could buy larger bags.

All item take far less space in your inventory in comparison with Diablo2. Now your items take 1-2 spaces.

Independent if it's a dagger or a flamberge will take only 2 spaces. While Belts and potions will take 1 space.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to increase the amount of space you have in the inventory of your character.

In town there is additional space for storage in a stash, and as of patch 2.1, there are now a maximum of 5 stash tabs.

If your stash is full, you can always create a level 1 character, have it run to the stash, and pull as much from the stash as possible into inventory as storage.

While this may encourage "hoarding" it is useful if you need more space in your stash and it has spilled over onto your main character's inventory.